# $f:S^2\to S^2$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres

Let $f:S^2\to S^2$ be a continuous with the property that it exists a nonempty,open $U\subseteq S^2$ with $f(x)=x$ for every $x\in U$ and $f(x)\notin U$ for $x\in S^2\setminus U$.

Prove that $f$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}: S^2\to S^2$.

My first idea was to take the homotopy

$H: S^2\times [0,1]\to S^2$ given by $(x,t)\mapsto \dfrac{tx+(1-t)f(x)}{\|tx+(1-t)f(x)\|}$.

For $x\in U$ this works.
For $x\in S^2\setminus U$ one has to argue that $tx+(1-t)f(x)\neq 0$ for every $t\in [0,1]$

If $tx+(1-t)f(x)=0$ for some $t$, then the direct line from $x$ to $f(x)$ has to intersect the origin, and therefor $f(x)=-x$, so $f(x)$ and $x$ are antipodal.

I tried to argue that this can not happen, but I did not succeed, and I do not think that this homotopy will be enough for a proof.

I have found this statement in a textbook:

For even $n$ has every continuous $f: S^n\to S^n$ a fixpoint or an antipodal point.
Someone knows if this is exclusive, or inclusive? So can such a continuous function have a fixpoint and an antipodal point?

I would like to know if my initial homotopy actually works, and it is worth trying to find the missing details, or if I should search for an other homotopy.

Comment: $\bf {Hint:}$ If $B^n$ denotes an open ball in $S^n$, $S^n - B$ is homeomorphic to the disk $D^n$. Try proving the Alexander trick: That every map $D^n \rightarrow D^n$ that is the identity on the boundary is homotopic to the identity, relative the boundary.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks for the suggestion. With some inspiration of the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick) I verified that the given isotopy is (or should be) a homotopy relative to the boundary. I do not see at the moment how that helps.

Comment: Since Connor already provided a hint, you might not care about the statement you found in the textbook anymore, but regarding your questions about it, I'll still add that fixed points and antipodal points are not exclusive. The constant map has one of both.

Comment: @ElliotYu I was still interested in an answer to that. Thanks. And yeah, that is a nice example I should have thought about myself.

Comment: Another hint: If you try to apply Connor's hint to $f$, you need to find an open ball, on the boundary of which $f$ is the identity. Where would you find such an open ball?

Comment: @ElliotYu Well, since $U\subseteq S^2$ is open, there is an open ball contained in $U$, for which $f$ then is the identity. What confuses me, is that I do not have that $f$ then is the identity on the boundary, but on $U$.

Comment: Right, so now you want to look at $f$ on the complement of that open ball contained in $U$. Intuitively, what we need is a homotopy to fix the value of $f$ on $S^2-U$. So you take a larger set that contains $S^2-U$, large enough that its boundary lies within $U$, where you know $f$ is the identity. (Correspondingly, the open ball you take needs to be small enough that its closure is in $U$.) Then by Alexander's trick, you can conclude that there is a homotopy that takes $f$ on this larger set to the identity.

Comment: Thanks, I think now I am able to do it, but I have to think about it later.

Comment: Since Connor's hints and our discussion so far is pretty close to a full answer, if you don't mind, I'll type it up and post as an answer later.

Comment: I do not mind, I might answer my question later myself, when I have worked out the details. Depending on how detailed your answer is, I might not accept it first.

Comment: That's alright. Definitely feel free to answer the question yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your homotopy does not work in general. If $U$ is "small", then $f(x) = -x$ is indeed possible for $x \in S^2 \setminus U$.

Choose $x_0 \in U$ and let $T$ denote the tangential plane to $S^2$ at $x_0$,  i.e. $T = \{ x_0 + y \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \langle x_0, y \rangle = 0 \}$. For $r \in (-1,1)$ define $T_r =  \{ rx_0 + y \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \langle x_0, y \rangle = 0 \}$. This is a plane which is parallel to $T$ and contains the point $rx_0$. It separates $S^2$ in two closed spherical caps
$C^+$ and $C^-$ such that $x_0 \in C^+$ and $-x_0 \in C^-$. Both caps are homeomorphic to the disk $D^2$. The intersection $S = C^+ \cap C^-$ is a circle which is the common boundary of the two caps.

For $r$ sufficiently close to $1$ we have $C^+ \subset U$. Clearly $f$ is identity on $C^+$ and in particular the identity on the $S$. By construction we have $f(C^-) \subset C^-$: If $x \in C^- \cap U$, then $f(x) = x \in C^-$ and if $x \in C^- \cap (S^2 \setminus U)$, then $f(x) \in S^2 \setminus U \subset S^2 \setminus  C^+ \subset C^-$.

Using the identification $h : C^- \stackrel{\approx}{\to} D^2$ we now see that $f : C^- \to C^-$ is homotopic to the identity rel. $S$ which implies that $f$ is homotopic to $id_{S^2}$. In fact, consider $g = h^{-1}f h : D^2  \to D^2$ which is the identity on $S^1$ and take the "linear homotopy" on $D^2$ from $g$ to $id$. This gives the desired homotopy on $C^-$.

Comment: ok that you have f that is homotopic to identity on U and also on S^2/U but how we conclude that f is homotopic to identity on S^2.

Comment: @Jale'dejaled I split $S^2$ into two closed spherical caps $C^+,C^−$ whose common boundary is the circle $S$. On $C^+$ the map f is the identity, on $C^−$ it is homotopic to the identity via a homotopy $H^−$ keeping fixed the points of $S$. Now the stationary homotopy $H^+$ on $C^+$ and $H^−$ fit together to a homotopy $H$ on $S^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly by construction of a homotopy as the other answers show.

A map $f \colon \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ can have antipodal and fixed points at the same time. For this view $\mathbb{S}^2$ as embedded in $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^3$ and put $f(z,x) = (z^2,x)$.
Then $f(0,1) = (0,1)$ is a fixed point and $f(-1,0) = (1,0)$ shows that $f$ has antipodal points.

Here a homological proof of the original statement:
$\require{AMScd}$
Pick $x \in U$ and an $1 > \varepsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $U' := B_\varepsilon(x)$ is in $U$, where $\mathbb{S}^2$ is equipped with the standard metric.
Let $V' = \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \overline B_{\varepsilon / 2} (x)$.
Clearly $f(U') \subset U'$ and $f(V') \subset V'$ and $f$ restricts to the identity on $U' \cap V'$. The fact that $\mathbb{S}^2 = U' \cup V'$ is an open cover yields a Mayer-Vietoris sequence which yields a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_2(U') \oplus H_2(V') @>>> H_2(\mathbb{S}) @>\partial>> H_1(U' \cap V') @>>> H_1(U') \oplus H_1(V')\\
@V V H_2(f|_{U'}) \oplus H_2(f|_{V'})  V @VV H_2(f)  V @VV H_2(f|_{U' \cap V'}) = \operatorname{id}_{H_2(U' \cap V')} V @V VH_1(f|_{U'}) \oplus H_1(f|_{V'}) V \\
H_2(U') \oplus H_2(V') @>>> H_2(\mathbb{S}) @>\partial>> H_1(U' \cap V') @>>> H_1(U') \oplus H_1(V')
\end{CD}
with exact rows. Now $\partial$ is an isomorphism as $U'$ and $V'$ are contractible. Hence, $H_2(f) = \operatorname{id}_{H_2(\mathbb{S}^2)}$. By the Hurewicz theorem $\pi_2(f) = \operatorname{id}_{\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^2)}$, hence $f = f \circ \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ by definition of $\pi_2(f)$.