# $f:S^2\to S^2$ which is unit on some ball $B\subset S^2$ then $f$ is homotopic to $Id_{S^2}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[$f:S^2\to S^2$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186675/fs2-to-s2-is-homotopic-to-operatornameid/4291015#4291015)

Considering above question and the first and selected answer.  $f$ is homotopic to identity on first cup and second cup and it is identity on the intersection circle.
How can we conclude the whole function is homotopic to identity.

If I have $f:X\to Y$ and $X=A\cup B$, $A,B\neq \emptyset$ if $f$'s restiriction on $A$ and $B$ are both homotopic to some $g$ with the same domain. Can we conclude $f\simeq g$

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not true. We need additional requirements to assure it. These are

1. $A,B$ are both open or both closed in $X$.
2. There are homotopies $H_A : A \times I \to Y$ from $f_A$ to $g_A$ and $H_B : B \times I \to Y$ from $f_B$ to $g_B$ which agree on $A \cap B$.

Then

$$H : X \times I \to Y, H(x,t) = \begin{cases} H_A(x,t) & x \in A \\ H_B(x,t) & x \in B \end{cases} $$
is well-defined and continuous.

Note that condition 2. is **necessary** for the existence od a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.